# Woocommerce do not display popup if 4 items in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, popup

I have some working code which is doing a conditional as follows to trigger a popup on the cart page...

- If Less than 8 items in cart, display popup with `elementor
  shortcode`.
- If 8 items or more, display popup with `wof_wheel`.

**How can I get it to not display the popup at all, if the number of items in the cart == 4?**

I thought by adding an if else, and by returning nothing it would work. But the popup still triggers.

**My Code:**

```
    //Shortcode Check 
function checkShortCode()
{
    $page = get_post(5);
    if (WC()->cart) {
        $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();


        if  ( $items_count < 8 ) {
            //Remove the Default Hook function for this shortcode
            remove_shortcode('wof_wheel');
            //Add custom callback for that short to display message required
            add_shortcode('wof_wheel', 'myCustomCallBack');
        }else if ($items_count == 4) {
        return; //Here I am trying to return nothing...
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'checkShortCode');

function myCustomCallBack()
{
    echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="3431"]');
}
```

Comment: When the item count is 4, the first condition < 8 is true already, so it has no reason to go into the else if branch in the first place … turn this around, and check for == 4 first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if/else statement doesn't work because `if ($items_count < 8)` returns `true` for `if ($items_count == 4)`. You should check on `if ($items_count == 4)` before checking on `if ($items_count < 8)`.

Hope this helps:

```
//Shortcode Check 
function checkShortCode()
{
    $page = get_post(5);
    if (WC()->cart) {
        $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        if ($items_count == 4) {
            return;
        } 
        if  ($items_count < 8) {
            //Remove the Default Hook function for this shortcode
            remove_shortcode('wof_wheel');
            //Add custom callback for that short to display message required
            add_shortcode('wof_wheel', 'myCustomCallBack');
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'checkShortCode');

function myCustomCallBack()
{
    echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="3431"]');
}
```

And you actually don't need `else if` because the `return` will stop the execution of the rest of the function.

Comment: Works perfectly. Yes and makes sense to check `items_count == 4` first before the larger one. Thanks!